# How to call a function from a Route in v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Previously, in react-router-dom v5 (or below) you could use:

`<Route path="/" render={() => {doSomething(); return <ComponentName />}} />`

to both fire a function and create a route without having to create any extra code inside of the ComponentName component. With `render` being replaced with `element` in v6, how do you now accomplish this?

Comment: What does `doSomething` do? Doing side effects during rendering isn't usually a good idea. The code should probably be called in a `useEffect`.

Comment: In this specific case, it involves analytics.  The above is a nice succinct way to add a helpful tracker (which only fires once) to many routes in one location without having to add that useEffect in each component.  Simple and DRY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer I came up with:

```
const doSomething = (arg1, component) => {
  //posting arg1 as an example of whatever you are wanting to do.
  console.log(arg1);
  return component;
};
```

```
<Route path="/" element={doSomething("string", <Home />)} />
```

Edit* *Marking this as the answer since it is most similar to the code in the original question, **but is is not the only correct answer**. Please consider the other great answer/s, which may be more appropriate, depending on your needs.*

Answer (score 8):

In `react-router-dom` v6 there are no longer any props to render a function in the `Route`, there exists the `element` prop that takes a JSX literal. Create a wrapper component that issues the side-effect, and wrap the component you are rendering on the route. Use the `useEffect` hook as unintentional side-effects in React should be avoided.

```
const DoSomethingWrapper = ({ children }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    doSomething();
  }, []);
  return children;
};
```

...

```
<Route
  path="/"
  element={(
    <DoSomethingWrapper>
      <ComponentName />
    </DoSomethingWrapper>
  )}
/>
```